# shell's command substitution not work : isSuc=$(db2 "update table_x set x=123"|grep successfully)

Tags: shell, command-substitution

This command can be executed successfully in my db2 server：

```
~]# db2 "update table_x set x=xxx"|grep successfully
```

With output:

```
~]# DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully
```

but if I execute this command:

```
~]# isSuc=$(db2 "update table_x set x=123"|grep successfully)
```

or:

```
~]# echo $(db2 "update table_x set x=123"|grep successfully)
```

`isSuc` does not get a value, and the `echo` outputs nothing. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try this:

```
 echo $( { db2 "update table_x set x=123" |grep successfully; } 2>&1 )
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not a solution but a direction. I've post my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
.../> echo $(db2 "update table_x set x=123")
DB20000I The SQL command completed successfully.

.../> echo $(db2 "update table_x set x=123"|grep DB)
DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a

.../> echo $(db2 "update table_x set x=123"|cat)
DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it returned: SQL1024N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003

.../> echo $(db2 connect to db_name &>/dev/null;db2 "update table_x set x=123"|grep successfully;)
DB20000I The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).